# Why does SDL render the background from the operating system to the window?

Tags: c++, sdl2

My code displays a fully transparent window that copies the background from the operating system.

[image: Window copies the OS background rendering]

This is the code I use for rendering:

```
void render()
{
    SDL_RenderClear(renderer);
    SDL_SetRenderDrawColor(renderer, 255, 0, 0, 255);
    SDL_RenderDrawRect(renderer, &background);
    SDL_RenderPresent(renderer);
}
```

And this is the code I use to create my window:

```
window = SDL_CreateWindow("title", posX, posY, windowWidth, windowHeight, SDL_WINDOW_OPENGL);
```

Comment: There are some issues with this question: the issue at hand is badly described, could you post some screenshots of the issue? It's not clear in the description what you're trying to achieve. There seems to be a lot of unnecessary code; trim that down to only what's important for the question. -- Please edit the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that you are passing the `SDL_WINDOW_OPENGL` flag to your window in `SDL_CreateWindow`, but then you are using the `SDL_Renderer` for rendering. You need to remove the flag for `SDL_Renderer` to function properly.